# Transversality of intersections of submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $S,S'$ be embedded submanifolds of a smooth manifold $M$. If $S\cap S'$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$, can anything be said about whether the intersection is transversal (possibly after restricting the situation further)?

Comment: Example: The intersection of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and the parabola $y=x^2-5/4$ is an embedded $0$-dimensional manifold, but they intersect tangentially. (You can put this in as many dimensions as you want.) Unless you introduce algebraic geometry and scheme structures, this phenomenon can always occur.